# Can't call GET /guilds/{id} discord Oauth

Tags: python, flask, oauth-2.0, postman, discord

So Im working in Postman at the moment for testing and have setup my OAuth2 Authorization Profile to get an access token. I am currently using all the scopes minus `bot` and `webhook.incoming`. The problem im encountering is not getting a valid token but rather not being able to really do too much with that token.

I can successfully get a response from `/users/@me` and `/users/@me/guilds` but I am getting `401: Unauthorized` when I make a call to `GET /guilds/{id}` where the ID is the id of a server I am the owner.

I have a feeling that the token granted from the OAuth flow only allows you to access certain endpoints but I feel like if I have the permissions of an owner I should be able to make a call to that endpoint after being authenticated.

Comment: Should probably post some code of what you're trying. And just in case you didn't know, selfbotting is against the rules and could get your account banned. I'd recommend using a bot user, if at all possible.

Comment: @0x464e thanks for the comment! I am using this for a web dashboard so no self botting but thanks for the heads up. I am away from my pc atm but here is the docs of the package im using with their basic usage example. I am essentially using a clone of this with an extra endpoint to view a specific server that you have "Manage Server" Permissions on